# iOS 13 frame animation is broken using UIViewPropertyAnimator

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiview, ios13

I have an array of `UIViewPropertyAnimator`'s, using it like in a WWDC video about animations, before iOS 13, everything works as expected, in iOS 13, the animations frame is not updating correctly. For example: 
I have an `UIViewPropertyAnimator` called `labelAnimator` which animates a label to some specific `CGRect`, that `CGRect` is not respected and  the label animates somewhere else.
Here is a video of the animation: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BcgkQp2zIsk
iOS 13 is on the left side, iOS 12 is on the right.

```
let textAnimator = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: duration, timingParameters: linearTiming)
            textAnimator.addAnimations {
                switch state{
                case .expanded:
                    self.tempLabel.transform =  CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.6, y: 0.6)
                    self.tempLabel.frame =  CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 15, y: self.diff / 2 - self.tempLabel.frame.height / 2), size: self.tempLabel.frame.size)
                case .collapsed:
                    self.tempLabel.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
                    self.tempLabel.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 15, y: self.view.frame.height / 2 - self.tempLabel.frame.height / 2 - 30), size: self.tempLabel.frame.size)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I am also having problems with animating the `frame` property. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Same issue for me.. I haven't found a solution yet, so please let me/us know if you find anything :)

Comment: I have the same issue, as the workaround, you can use `UIView.animate` function

Comment: nope same issue with UIView.animate and origin.frame = target.frame

Comment: Also found issues in frame animations and constraint animations, I have solved in my case by just assigning value little high to 0. eg. lets say you want to animate view's height from 500 to 0, then put 1 or 0.1 value instead of 0. Hope it will be helpful for some cases.

Comment: Still not fixed as of iOS 13.4ß6.